# Add reference to server for CLR stored procedure in VS2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, clrstoredprocedure

I need to add a reference to a CLR stored procedure that I have not deployed yet. The dll I need is on a remote server that I am connected to, according to the Database section under the solution properties. If I simply select References->Add Reference I cannot see the dll I need. I tried "Add Service Reference" and entered "jdbc:sqlserver://serverName\instanceName, however that gave me the following message:

"The MetadataExchangeClient instance could not be initialized because no Binding is available for scheme 'jdbc'. You can supply a Binding in the constructor, or specify a configurationName.
Parameter name: scheme
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again."

This is the first time I've done this, so I could also be going in the completely wrong direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just an access/location issue. The dll was not showing up because it was in the wrong folder.